# opening html tags in c# by regular expression

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, tags

I have to find all the opening HTML tags (by regular expression) How do I do that?
I tried the following expression: (<. +?>) And it gives me both the openers and the closing ones
Note: An opening tag can show <> or so </>
i work with c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this regular expression:

```
<[^/][^\n]+?>
```

It should find all opening HTML tags, but not closing ones.

It works because of this `[^/]` negated set, finding all characters except for `/` as the first character of the match. The second set `[^\n]` finds all characters except for linebreaks (`\n`)

Comment: This phrase does not give opening tags that do not have a closing tag such as <br />
Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer, <br /> and others will now work.